# Get the sum of total & individual within the group in python

Tags: python

I am reading this data from a csv AND trying to find the top 2 channels and its video along with their sum of revenue and views.
I also want to sort the results based on top revenue of channels.
How can I do this in python, I tried in mysql which did not work for me. Any help is appreciated.

Input

```
channel_name    video   views   revenue
abc             v1       1       4
abc             v2       1       5
abc             v2       1       5
efg             v3       2       3
ijk             v4       3       2
```

Expected output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBQbL.png)

Comment: I would look into the pandas package. Here is a tutorial : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas `grouby()` and `sum()` functions. The result will already be sorted ascending:

```
In [4]: df
Out[4]:
  channel_name video  views  revenue
0          abc    v1      1        4
1          abc    v2      1        5
2          abc    v2      1        5
3          efg    v3      2        3
4          ijk    v4      3        2

In [5]: grouped = df.groupby(['channel_name', 'video'])

In [6]: grouped.sum()
Out[6]:
                    views  revenue
channel_name video
abc          v1         1        4
             v2         2       10
efg          v3         2        3
ijk          v4         3        2
```

If you want the indexes to be columns:

```
In [7]: grouped.sum().reset_index()
Out[7]:
  channel_name video  views  revenue
0          abc    v1      1        4
1          abc    v2      2       10
2          efg    v3      2        3
3          ijk    v4      3        2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.groupby(['channel_name','video'])[['views','revenue']].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

First option:

```
data_group = data.groupby(by=['channel_name', 'video']).sum()
data_group.head()
                      views revenue
channel_name    video       
abc              v1      1      4
                 v2      2      10
efg              v3      2      3
ijk              v4      3      2
```

Second Option:

```
data_group = data.groupby(by=['channel_name', 'video']).agg({'views': 'sum', 'revenue': 'sum'})
data_group.head()

                          views revenue
    channel_name    video       
    abc              v1      1      4
                     v2      2      10
    efg              v3      2      3
    ijk              v4      3      2
```

Third option keeping the columns:

```
data_group = data_group.reset_index()

data_group.head()
    channel_name    video   views   revenue
0        abc          v1      1       4
1        abc          v2      2      10
2        efg          v3      2       3
3        ijk          v4      3       2
```